# How likely is istream::ungetc() to work with a stringbuf (as used in stringstream)?

Tags: c++, stringstream, istream

I've tried searching for the answer, but nothing mentions stringstream specifically. I would guess that it would always work and you can always go back as far as the beginning of the underlying string.

Am I right?

Comment: _"How likely ..."_ Are you serious? There's nothing like _likely_, but there's [a reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/ungetc). establishing facts.

Comment: Well, [`std::ungetc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/ungetc) works with a `FILE*` , and there's no relation to `std::stringstream`.

Comment: I'm talking about <stringstream>/<istream>, not <cstdio>.

Comment: So you actually want [`std::basic_istream::unget()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget)?

Comment: I want to know if basic_istream::unget() works with stringbuf and how far back you can go.

Comment: Ask clear questions then please. You can go back as much the underlying buffer is able to hold.

Answer (score 2):

> How likely is istream::ungetc() to work with a stringbuf (as used in stringstream)?

Well, never.

There's no such thing like `istream::ungetc()` defined from the standard.

You can use either

[`int std::ungetc( int ch, std::FILE *stream )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/ungetc)

or

[`std::basic_istream& std::basic_istream::unget()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget)